# Rails: create column with same name as parent

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Ruby on rails with MySQL and I created 2 models: Users, Accounts
where Accounts belongs to Users and User has many Accounts.

By accident I create a column user in the account model and I noticed whenever I retrieve now a record from accounts and render it with JSON all the fields from user will be included too.

This was quite convenient for my application since I needed the full set of data anyway.

My frontend (works on Angular) is now manipulating the account data and I send the new record for an update back to the rails server. But when I call the account.update_attributes() function in my controller, then rails will not only update the account record but also try to update the user record which leads to an error (and I dont want the user data to be updated). How can I stop rails from updating the associated user records?

I know I can remove the user data from params - thats very easy but a very static solution I cannot use for other tables which are more generic than the example above.

I was also wondering it is anywhere documented giving a column the name of an associated parent model will lead to this kind of behaviour? functionality?

Comment: how about creating and running a migration to change the name of the user column in the Account model?

Comment: How does this help me? I only named one field by accident 'user' and now I can access the linked model wish is great when retrieving the data. But I don't want to update the linked user record when updating the account record. Migrating my column user to a different name will resolve my update problem but I cannot access the linked record anymore when reading it.

Comment: I migrated now to MongoDB where I didnt face this issue so far.